# I can't make a data frame with lagged variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I want to create a data frame with 1,2 and 3 years lagged values; ie. 1:4 start=1900  frec=1

```
year      actual_value      lagged_1      lagged_2      lagged_3
1900      1                  NA            NA            NA
1901      2                  1             NA            NA
1902      3                  2             1             NA
1903      4                  3             2             1
```

I'm using the "nhtemp" dataset from "dataset" package

I tried this:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    lag <- stats::lag

    dat <- tibble(
      year = time(nhtemp),
      temp = nhtemp,
      temp_lag1 = lag(nhtemp, -1),
      temp_lag2 = lag(nhtemp, -2),
      temp_lag3 = lag(nhtemp, -3)
    )
```

but the output is the following:

```
head(dat)
    year  temp temp_lag1 temp_lag2 temp_lag3
      <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
    1  1912  49.9      49.9      49.9      49.9
    2  1913  52.3      52.3      52.3      52.3
    3  1914  49.4      49.4      49.4      49.4
    4  1915  51.1      51.1      51.1      51.1
    5  1916  49.4      49.4      49.4      49.4
    6  1917  47.9      47.9      47.9      47.9`
```

Comment: It should be `lag <- dplyr::lag`. This is a duplicate.

Comment: ^ to add to this, `base::lag` shifts the time base of a time series, without changing the data -- ie element 1 would remain element 1, just with earlier time assigned to it. "Compute a lagged version of a time series, shifting the time base back by a given number of observations."  `dplyr::lag` sounds like the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: consider running `library(tidyverse)` then do not run the `lag <- stats::lag` you should not use this anyway. then run your code. Also use positive lags ie `lag(x, 1), lag(x, 2) etc.. if you need to use negative values, use `lead` instead

Comment: If i do not use stats::lag an error pops up -> Error in `lag()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a <ts>, do you want `stats::lag()`?

Comment: `datasets::nhtemp |> tsibble::as_tsibble() |> mutate(temp_lag1 = lag(value, 1),  temp_lag2 = lag(value, 2),  temp_lag3 = lag(value, 3))`. The data set is a time series object, while dplyr expects a data frame, and `dplyr::lag` expects a vector (typically within a data frame). The `tsibble` package can convert a variety of time series objects into a data frame (with some extra attributes useful for time series).